# Android Layouts like FB Messenger

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have layout similar to Facebook messenger that the bottom EditView and Button are always on bottom and the main part is scrollable.

How should it look like ?
I wrote something like :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        android:hint="write here.." />

</ScrollView>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following layout to allow you to have a header & footer with scrollable content:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_control_bar">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sort_by"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"></ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Source: http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/

To achieve a chat layout similar to Facebook Messenger take a look at these:

http://warting.se/2012/06/04/chat-bubbles-in-android/

http://warting.github.io/AndroidChatBubbles/